# Express App.error doesn't work with Node.js 0.8.0 What should I do

Tags: node.js, express

I have just installed Node 0.8.0 and also updated express.
However, app.error doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to fix or go around this issue?  thanks.

Comment: Oh.. this?
 app.use(function(err,req,res,next){});

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

**Removed:**
- app.error() (use middleware with (err, req, res, next))